# Kotlin ? vs ?.let {}

Tags: kotlin

Consider this nice utility extension function i wanted to use :

```
inline infix fun <T> T?.otherwise(other: () -> Unit): T? {
    if (this != null) return this
    other()
    return null
}
```

It could be very useful for logging stuff when expressions evaluated to null for example:

```
val x: Any? = null
x?.let { doSomeStuff() } otherwise {Log.d(TAG,"Otherwise happened")}
```

but I see that it wont work for :

```
val x: Any? = null
x?.otherwise {Log.d(TAG,"Otherwise happened")}
```

see [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjQxIiwiY29kZSI6IlxuaW5saW5lIGluZml4IGZ1biA8VD4gVD8ub3RoZXJ3aXNlKG90aGVyOiAoKSAtPiBVbml0KTogVD8ge1xuICAgIGlmICh0aGlzICE9IG51bGwpIHJldHVybiB0aGlzXG4gICAgb3RoZXIoKVxuICAgIHJldHVybiBudWxsXG59XG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCB4OiBBbnk/ID0gbnVsbFxuICAgIHg/LmxldCB7fSBvdGhlcndpc2Uge3ByaW50bG4oXCIxXCIpfVxuICAgIHg/Lm90aGVyd2lzZSB7cHJpbnRsbihcIjJcIil9XG59IiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiJ9) for running example

Well when thinking about it i guess that makes sense that if `x` is null the `?` makes the postfix not be executed, but i dont understand why the `let` in the first example is any different?

Is it possible to fix the utility to be more robust and work without having to have `let` in the chain?

Comment: Why do you need `otherwise` function? Don't you like [elvis](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) operator `x?.let { print("not null") } ?: print("null")`? Only disadvantage is using `run` for more complex staff: `x?.let { print("not null") } ?: run { print("null") }`

Comment: For your second case it will be `x ?: print("null")` or `x ?: run { print("null") }`.

Comment: @Vadik No, i dont like it since it makes my code very unreadable, even to me

Comment: Of course you are free to do what you want, but I agree with @Vadik that replacing language features with your own implementations is not a good idea. It gives you more potential code that will break and require maintainance, and it is surprising to people new to the codebase. Remember the [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). You also cannot hide from the language syntax when looking at other projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can simplify the implementation:

```
inline infix fun <T> T?.otherwise(other: () -> Unit): T? {
    if (this == null) { other() }
    return this
}
```

Or

```
inline infix fun <T> T?.otherwise(other: () -> Unit): T? =
    also { if (it == null) other() }
```

---

When you do this:

```
null?.otherwise { println("Otherwise happened") }
```

`?.` means "execute if not null", so `otherwise` is not executed.

What you need to write is:

```
null otherwise { println("Otherwise happened") }
```

Note this is very similar to the `?:` operator (as Vadik pointed out in the comments):

```
null ?: println("Otherwise happened")
```

The difference is that `otherwise` always returns the value on the left (the same as [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html)), but `?:` returns the value on the right when the value on the left is null.

In my opinion, `otherwise` is confusing, especially as it always returns the left value despite the name. You would be better to use the `?:` operator. Or perhaps rename it to something like `alsoIfNull`.

Comment: hmmm you got it wrong i return null when other() is executed (you dont)

Comment: @OfekRon yes I do - it's exactly the same logic: `execute other and return null, or don't execute other and return the non-null value`. Just expressed more clearly as `execute other if null, and return the receiver (whether null or not)`.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip you are right, better code indeed

Comment: @AdamMillerchip and you are also right that ifNull is a better name (removed also though)

Comment: @OfekRon the reason I suggested `alsoIfNull` is that it behaves similar to the `also` standard library function. In fact, you could also implement it with also, added an example.

Answer (score 2):

The `let` example executes because, when you don't utilize the infix feature, it looks like this:

```kotlin
x?.let {}.otherwise {println("1")}
```

Notice that it's not `?.otherwise`; therefore, it always executes.

So to use `otherwise` without `let`, you can omit the `?`.

```kotlin
x.otherwise { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x?.let { doSomeStuff() }.otherwise {Log.d(TAG,"Otherwise happened")}
// ⬇️
val value = if (x != null) {
    doSomeStuff()
} else {
    null
}
value.otherwise {Log.d(TAG,"Otherwise happened")}
```

```
x?.otherwise { Log.d(TAG,"Otherwise happened") }
// ⬇️
if (x != null) {
    otherwise { Log.d(TAG,"Otherwise happened") }
} else {
    null
}
```

`?.` means if the value is not null then execute the method and return the result otherwise return null

Comment: In the second example, `x!!.otherwise { Log.d(TAG,"Otherwise happened") }` would be more accurate (the `!!` is redundant, because `x` is smart-cast to not null, but it demonstrates `x` is not null here).